# Deploy LibGDX game with embedded java for single board computers with Linux

Tags: java, gradle, raspberry-pi, libgdx, jpackage

I try to deploy a videogame made with LibGDX for Raspberry Pi. My customer has a specific old version of Raspbian that can not more updated and a java can not be installed. Previous games for him were created using Lua and Love2D. I have created a videogame using Java and LibGDX. To launch the game on his Raspberry Pi 3B I need to integrate Java in the game. I have tried to use JPackage. It works perfect on Windows. But it doesn't work on Ubuntu X64 (I use Khadas Vim3 pro) and Raspberry Pi OS 64 bit (I tested on my Raspberry Pi 4B). It shows an error. My build.gradle file in the desktop module:

```
jpackage {
    String moduleName = project.name.toString()
    String moduleDir = project.projectDir.toString();
    int startModuleChar = moduleDir.indexOf(moduleName)
    String projectDir = moduleDir.substring(0,startModuleChar)
    String pathToJdk;
    if (osName.contains('windows')) {
        pathToJdk = projectDir+File.separator+'jdks'+File.separator+'Win64'+File.separator+'jdk'

    }
    else {
        String architecture = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");
        if (architecture.contains('32')){
            System.out.println("This is Linux 32 bit")
            pathToJdk = projectDir+'jdks'+File.separator+'arm32'+File.separator+'jdk-14.0.2+12'
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("This is Linux 64 bit")
            pathToJdk = projectDir+'jdks'+File.separator+'arm64'+File.separator+'jdk-14.0.2+12'
            try{
                File jdk = new File(pathToJdk);
                System.out.println("Dir exists: " + jdk.exists());
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    jpackageHome = pathToJdk

    mainJar = dist.archiveFileName.get()
    if (osName.contains('windows')) {
        imageOptions = ["--icon", file("../icons/icon.ico")]
    } else if (osName.contains('linux')) {
        imageOptions = ["--icon", file("../icons/icon.png")]
    } else if (osName.contains('mac')) {
        imageOptions = ["--icon", file("../icons/icon.icns")]
    }
}
```

And it fails and I receive the next error message in the output:

```
Task :desktop:jpackageImage
The jpackage task is experimental. Use it at your own risk.
/home/khadas/GD/Workspace/airfight_ussr_14.04.2023/airfight_ussr/jdks/arm64/jdk-14.0.2+12/bin/jpackage: 1: ELF: not found
/home/khadas/GD/Workspace/airfight_ussr_14.04.2023/airfight_ussr/jdks/arm64/jdk-14.0.2+12/bin/jpackage: 9: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

> Task :desktop:jpackageImage FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':desktop:jpackageImage'.

> Process 'command '/home/khadas/GD/Workspace/airfight_ussr_14.04.2023/airfight_ussr/jdks/arm64/jdk-14.0.2+12/bin/jpackage'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

When I run with the stacktrace I receive:

> - Exception is:
>   org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':desktop:jpackageImage'.
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:207)
>   at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:263)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:205)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:114)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
>   at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
>   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:370)
>   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:357)
>   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:350)
>   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
>   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
>   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
>   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
>   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
>   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
>   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
>   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
>   Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/khadas/GD/Workspace/airfight_ussr_14.04.2023/airfight_ussr/jdks/arm64/jdk-14.0.2+12/bin/jpackage'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
>   at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:417)
>   at org.gradle.process.ExecResult$assertNormalExitValue.call(Unknown Source)
>   at org.beryx.runtime.impl.JPackageImageTaskImpl.execute(JPackageImageTaskImpl.groovy:91)
>   at org.beryx.runtime.JPackageImageTask.jpackageTaskAction(JPackageImageTask.groovy:75)
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:49)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:42)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:722)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:689)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:569)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:554)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:537)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$300(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:108)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:278)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:267)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:67)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:36)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:49)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:34)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:43)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:34)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:44)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:54)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:38)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:159)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:72)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:43)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:44)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:33)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:92)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:85)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:39)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:94)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:49)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:79)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:53)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:74)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:39)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:40)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:28)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:194)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:114)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
>   at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
>   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:370)
>   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:357)
>   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:350)
>   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
>   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
>   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
>   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
>   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
>   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
>   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
>   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)

What is wrong and how can I deploy my game with the embedded java (not lower as Java 11)?

Comment: I have tried to use an another tool to create the executable launcher. I used parcl https://github.com/mini2Dx/parcl . It works on Windows x64 but it doesn't work on my Raspberry Pi 4B with Raspberry Pi OS X64. It creates a launchable sh-file and saved the JDK in the folder with the output. But it doesn't launch the game